# Which expression is correct: 'for working with' or 'to work with'

Tags: expressions

For me it seems that in the following case expression seems not to be fitting, I think the second example is shorter, simpler and may even be more correct.

1. dugite - Elegant bindings for working with Git in your Node applications
2. dugite - Elegant bindings to work with Git in your Node applications

Comment: Either is OK.  Their meaning is extremely similar.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to reserve the to-form of a verb for when there is some intention to achieve a result. If not, I generally change to an ing-form of the verb. Not always, mind you. Doing that just feels a bit more precise to me.

Comment: @Sasha Tobin what is that, please? A glossary entry giving a quick explanation? It looks like a definition, in which case "for working" would trump "to work with".

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 sounds more natural to me assuming you want to imply that someone is working with Git using the bindings.

Option 2 can be read as similar to "bindings that work with Git", i.e., bindings that are compatible with Git.

Answer (score 0):

For what Dugite does, the first is preferable because the goal is actively working with Git from node.

"work with" is more often used to convey compatibility between things.

So, you could say

> Dugite will work with Git, but not Subversion, and is an elegant solution for working on repos from your node client.